# SQL Question : Technical question that requires you to answer How many members worked at IBM before working at Google?

Tags: sql

Assume the following dataset:

| member_id | company | Year_started |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 2001 |
| 1 | IBM | 2002 |
| 1 | Oracle | 2005 |
| 1 | Microsoft | 2010 |
| 2 | IBM | 2002 |
| 2 | Microsoft | 2004 |
| 2 | Oracle | 2008 |

Member 1, began work at IBM in 2002, moved to Oracle in 2005 and moved to Microsoft in 2010. Member 2, began workin gat IBM in 2002, moved to Microsoft in 2004 and then Moved to oracle in 2008. Assume that for each member in each year, there is only one company (cannot work at 2 different companies in the same year).

**Question: How many members ever worked at IBM prior to working at Oracle? **

How would you go about solving this? I tried a combination of CASE when's but am lost as to where else to go. Thanks.
...
..

Comment: Show your *combination of CASE*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would phrase this using `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT member_id
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE company = 'Google' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.member_id = t1.member_id AND
                    t2.company = 'IBM' AND
                    t2.Year_started < t1.Year_started);
```

In plain English, the above query says to report every employee who worked at Google in some year, for which there is a record from an *earlier* year for the same employee who worked at IBM at that time.

Comment: Did not know the EXIST function even existed (no pun intended), thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would go for querying the table twice and then join like so:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select member_id, min(Year_started) y
    from my_table
    where company = 'IBM'
    group by member_id
) i
join (
    select member_id, max(Year_started) y
    from my_table
    where company = 'Oracle'
    group by member_id
) o on i.member_id = o.member_id and i.y < o.y
```

Note the difference of min/max functions on the year column. This would yield a match for the use case Oracle-IBM-Oracle as well as IBM-Oracle-IBM.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a *self join*:

```
select count(distinct m1.member_id)
from members m1
join members m2
  on m1.member_id = m2.member_id and m1.Year_started < m2.Year_started
where m1.company = 'IBM' and m2.company = 'Oracle';
```

Answer (score 0):

More verbose, but using CTEs:

1. For each `member_id`, get the first year they worked at IBM (if any), and get the first year they worked at Oracle (again, if any).

   - "For each `member_id`" translates to `GROUP BY member_id`
   - "Get the first year..." translates to `MIN( CASE WHEN "Company" = 'etc' THEN "Year_Started" END )`
2. Filter those rows to rows where the first-year-at-IBM is less-than their first-year-at-Oracle.
3. Then simply get the `COUNT(*)` of those rows.

```sql
WITH ibmOracleYears AS (
    SELECT
        member_id,
        MIN( CASE WHEN "Company" = 'IBM'    THEN "Year_Started" END ) AS JoinedIbm,
        MIN( CASE WHEN "Company" = 'Oracle' THEN "Year_Started" END ) AS JoinedOracle
    FROM
        yourTable
    GROUP BY
        member_id
),
workedAtIbmBeforeOracle AS (
    SELECT
        y.*
    FROM
        ibmOracleYears AS y
    WHERE
        y.JoinedIbm IS NOT NULL   /* <-- This `IS NOT NULL` check isn't absolutely necessary, but I'm including it for clarity. */
        AND
        y.JoinedOracle IS NOT NULL
        AND
        y.JoinedIbm < y.JoinedOracle
)
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS "Number of members that worked at IBM before Oracle"
FROM
    workedAtIbmBeforeOracle
```

But that query can be reduced down to this (if you don't mind anonymous expressions in `HAVING` clauses):

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS "Number of members that worked at IBM before Oracle"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            member_id 
        FROM
            yourTable
        GROUP BY
            member_id
        HAVING
            MIN( CASE WHEN "Company" = 'IBM' THEN "Year_Started" END ) < MIN( CASE WHEN "Company" = 'Oracle' THEN "Year_Started" END )
    ) AS q
```

[SQLFiddle of both examples](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2cb0d/4).